# Is there any Stack Overflow SDK available for Android?

Tags: support, api

Is any Stack Overflow SDK available for Android? Or any API call available so that I just get all the questions and answers of particular user with or without login?

I can see one app is available in Google Play Store, but it is based on a `WebView` (Browser based).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [StackExchange API](http://api.stackexchange.com).

It covers [most](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs) of the functionality of the site and it is used by various apps, including StackExchange's own apps for Android and iOS.

Authentication is done through OAuth. I am sure you can find some libraries to help with that.

If you need more help on developing apps using the API, [StackApps](http://stackapps.com) is the place to go.

Comment: Thanks Patrick. let me try one